# SQL*Plus how to execute environment set-up and query in one statement

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle12c, sqlplus

I execute the following query which returns one value and it works fine.

```
echo "select myquery ;" | sqlplus user/pass@dbase | | head -4 | tail -1
```

The issue is that when the one value returned is too large it gets split in multiple rows thus the ETL tool that I further use gets problems.
Therefore I have tried to use the linesize option but I am not able to combine it with the query.

If I connect to sqlplus and run:
`SET LINESIZE 3200` followed by `select myquery ;` the output is fine but I am not able to combine them in the echo statement.
I have tried in different ways, for example:

```
echo "SET LINESIZE 3200 / select myquery ;" | sqlplus user/pass@dbase | | head -4 | tail -1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heredoc (as shown in @Philippe's answer) is going to be easier to read and maintain, but if for some reason you really wanted to keep it in one line you could add the `-e` flag to `echo` and embed new lines:

```
echo -e "SET LINESIZE 3200 \n select myquery ;" | sqlplus user/pass@dbase | head -4 | tail -1
```

or use `printf`:

```
printf "set linesize 3200 \n select myquery ;\n" | sqlplus user/pass@dbase | head -4 | tail -1
```

(In both I've taken out the extra `|` from your original version)

You can extend this to avoid the need to head and tail the output:

```
printf "set linesize 3200 \n set pagesize 0 \n set feedback off \n select myquery ;\n" | sqlplus -s user/pass@dbase
```

or with the various `set` options combined:

```
printf "set linesize 3200 pagesize 0 feedback off \n select myquery ;\n" | sqlplus -s user/pass@dbase
```

The `-s` suppresses the banner; from the head/tail values you're using I imagine you already have that and just didn't show it. (I'd usually throw in `-l` as well, so it doesn't get stuck if the credentials are wrong.) The other `set` commands remove the column headings and "1 row selected." message.

While that's a longer single command line overall, it has the advantage of not manipulating/mangling any error output you might get.

Or as a heredoc:

```
sqlplus -l -s user/pass@dbase <<EOF
set linesize 3200
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
select myquery ;
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this :

```
sqlplus user/pass@dbase << "EOF" |...| head -4 | tail -1
SET LINESIZE 3200;
select myquery ;
EOF
```

Comment: can I put them in one line ? - this is what the ETL tool expects